# ERROR TypeError: .filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

please help me to resolve this error in Angular.
I know filter method works with array , not with object. But still not able to typecast object into array (data is coming through API) or in any other way. Please help me to solve this issue. I am begineer in Angular.

I am trying to make AutoComplete Search text box using the data coming through API.
Please help me.

.component.html:-

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
     [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
        {{option.email}} , {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

.service.ts:-

```
opts = [];
    searchRecord(url: string, params: any){

        let httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', //'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; application/json; charset=utf-8'
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')).token
            })
        };

        // return this.http.post<any>(this.url + url, JSON.stringify(params), httpOptions);
        return this.opts.length ? of(this.post) : this.http.post<any>(this.url + url, JSON.stringify(params),
         httpOptions).pipe(tap(data => (this.opts = data)));
    }
```

.component.ts:-

```
import { Component, Injectable , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, startWith, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-existent-application',
  templateUrl: './existent-application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./existent-application.component.css']
})

export class ExistentApplicationComponent implements OnInit {


public requestUserData = {
  "searchString": " " , 
  "applicantId": 0, 
  "city": [],
  "Province": [],
  "ProfileComplete": [], 
  "countryID": [],
  "AgentID": [],
  "BranchID": [],
  "AgencyID": []
}

name: string = "";
dataInTable: any;

myControl = new FormControl();                                   
  
options: any;  //Getting Data from API 
filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private service: GeneralService) { 
 this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(val => {
        return this.filter(val || "");
      })
    );

ngOnInit(): void {
    let url: string = '/applicant/getApplicantListfiltered';
    this.service.searchRecord(url, this.requestUserData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        if (res.message == 'Ok') {
            this.requestUserData = res.data;
            // localStorage.setItem('requestUserData', JSON.stringify(res.data));
            // console.log(res.data);
            this.dataInTable = res.data;
            console.log(this.dataInTable);
            console.log(typeof(this.dataInTable));
           
        }
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
      });
  }

filter(val: any) {
    // call the service which makes the http-request
    let url: string = '/applicant/getApplicantListfiltered';
    return this.service.searchRecord(url, this.requestUserData).pipe(
      map (res => 
        res.filter(option => {
          return (option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
        })
      ) 
    );
  }

[Please check the error screenshot here]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUwWQ.png

[Please check the API Data screenshot here]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6B4t.png
```

Comment: Share your response example here for more reference

Comment: assign any type to the res  (res:any)